# Gray code in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, error-checking, gray-code

Is there a built in [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) datatype anywhere in the .NET framework?  Or conversion utility between Gray and binary?  I could do it myself, but if the wheel has already been invented...

Comment: Thanks for the wikipedia link. Never heard about gray codes and this made for some interesting reading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [this trick](http://www.dspguru.com/comp.dsp/tricks/alg/grayconv.htm).

```
/*
        The purpose of this function is to convert an unsigned
        binary number to reflected binary Gray code.
*/
unsigned short binaryToGray(unsigned short num)
{
        return (num>>1) ^ num;
}
```

A tricky Trick: for up to 2^n bits, you can convert Gray to binary by
performing (2^n) - 1 binary-to Gray conversions. All you need is the
function above and a 'for' loop.

```
/*
        The purpose of this function is to convert a reflected binary
        Gray code number to a binary number.
*/
unsigned short grayToBinary(unsigned short num)
{
        unsigned short temp = num ^ (num>>8);
        temp ^= (temp>>4);
        temp ^= (temp>>2);
        temp ^= (temp>>1);
       return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a C# implementation that assumes you only want to do this on non-negative 32-bit integers:

```
static uint BinaryToGray(uint num)
{
    return (num>>1) ^ num;
}
```

You might also like to read [this blog post](http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/a-gray-code-mini-library-in-c/) which provides methods for conversions in both directions, though the author chose to represent the code as an array of `int` containing either one or zero at each position.  Personally I would think a `BitArray` might be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this collection of methods is useful

- based on BitArray
- both directions
- int or just n Bits

just enjoy.

```
public static class GrayCode
{
    public static byte BinaryToByte(BitArray binary)
    {
        if (binary.Length > 8)
            throw new ArgumentException("bitarray too long for byte");

        var array = new byte[1];
        binary.CopyTo(array, 0);
        return array[0];
    }

    public static int BinaryToInt(BitArray binary)
    {
        if (binary.Length > 32)
            throw new ArgumentException("bitarray too long for int");

        var array = new int[1];
        binary.CopyTo(array, 0);
        return array[0];
    }

    public static BitArray BinaryToGray(BitArray binary)
    {
        var len = binary.Length;
        var gray = new BitArray(len);
        gray[len - 1] = binary[len - 1]; // copy high-order bit
        for (var i = len - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            // remaining bits 
            gray[i] = binary[i] ^ binary[i + 1];
        }
        return gray;
    }

    public static BitArray GrayToBinary(BitArray gray)
    {
        var len = gray.Length;
        var binary = new BitArray(len);
        binary[len - 1] = gray[len - 1]; // copy high-order bit
        for (var i = len - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            // remaining bits 
            binary[i] = !gray[i] ^ !binary[i + 1];
        }
        return binary;
    }

    public static BitArray ByteToGray(byte value)
    {
        var bits = new BitArray(new[] { value });
        return BinaryToGray(bits);
    }

    public static BitArray IntToGray(int value)
    {
        var bits = new BitArray(new[] { value });
        return BinaryToGray(bits);
    }

    public static byte GrayToByte(BitArray gray)
    {
        var binary = GrayToBinary(gray);
        return BinaryToByte(binary);
    }

    public static int GrayToInt(BitArray gray)
    {
        var binary = GrayToBinary(gray);
        return BinaryToInt(binary);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns the bits as string of '0' and '1' (LSB is right)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bits"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string AsString(this BitArray bits)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(bits.Length);
        for (var i = bits.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sb.Append(bits[i] ? "1" : "0");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<bool> Bits(this BitArray bits)
    {
        return bits.Cast<bool>();
    }

    public static bool[] AsBoolArr(this BitArray bits, int count)
    {
        return bits.Bits().Take(count).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful but it is missing an `IntToBinary` function. And if each function is independent of other functions it could have been great.

Comment: IntToBinary: `var bits = new BitArray(new[] { value });`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing *built-in* as far as Gray code in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

[Graphical Explanation](http://www.wisc-online.com/Objects/ViewObject.aspx?ID=IAU8307) about Gray code conversion - this can help a little